# Mysterious inequality behavior when comparing date strings

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, collation, cast

Can someone explain this mysterious Postgres behavior? I'm performing the following queries at the `psql` command line.

```
mydb=> select '20150526' > '2015-05-25';
-[ RECORD 1 ]
?column? | t

mydb=> select '20150526' > '2015-05-26';
-[ RECORD 1 ]
?column? | f

mydb=> select '20150526' > '2015-05-27';
-[ RECORD 1 ]
?column? | f
```

If Postgres was actually comparing the strings directly, either all three would be true or false, depending on how character ordering is defined. This seems to establish that Postgres is trying to convert the strings to dates before comparison, presumably based on some heuristic about the formats. However:

```
mydb=> select '20150526' < '2015-05-27';
-[ RECORD 1 ]
?column? | t

mydb=> select '20150526' < '2015-05-26';
-[ RECORD 1 ]
?column? | t

mydb=> select '20150526' < '2015-05-25';
-[ RECORD 1 ]
?column? | f
```

Note that the result of the middle query is incorrect, if interpreted heuristically as dates! The inverse issue occurs with the `>=` operator. This caused an extremely subtle bug in a trigger function I'm using.

So, two mysteries:

1. Postgres seems to be heuristically interpreting these strings as dates in order to do comparisons. This is a little surprising, so I would like confirmation.
2. The results are wrong for the `<` and `>=` operators when the dates are the same but in different formats. This seems like a bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What makes you think you are comparing ***dates***?

Actually, you are comparing **string literals** which - in the absence of a cast context and any explicit cast - default to **`text`**:

```
SELECT '20150526' > '2015-05-26' AS text2text
     , '20150526'::date > '2015-05-26'::date AS date2date;

text2text | date2date
----------+----------
 t        | f
```

Try:

```
SELECT pg_typeof(col) FROM (VALUES ('20150527')) t(col);  -- no cast

pg_typeof
---------
text
```

The result of your comparison of `text` values depends on your locale, on [`COLLATION` rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html) to be precise. To see the default `COLLATION` of your session:

```
SHOW lc_collate;
```

`COLLATION` can be also be set per column or even per expression. To see the actual `COLLATION` for any expression use the [`collation for (any)` construct](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE):

```
SELECT collation for (my_column) FROM tbl LIMIT 1;
```

To test how strings are sorted in your locale:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   VALUES
     ('20150526')
   , ('2015-05-25')
   , ('20150525')
   , ('2015-05-26')
   , ('20150527')
   , ('2015-05-27')
   ) t(col)
ORDER BY col;    -- COLLATE "C"
```

Compare this to the sort order by pure byte-value by appending `COLLATE "C"` to `ORDER BY`. To see the result of your comparison with a different `COLLATION`:

```
SELECT '20150526' > '2015-05-26' COLLATE "C" AS text2text_c;
```

Comment: Thank you!

To extend this answer a bit, my database defaults to `en_US.UTF-8` and the default sorting rule ignores punctuation. Apparently this descends from Unix behavior (see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35469/why-does-ls-sorting-ignore-non-alphanumeric-characters)).

Comment: Correction: it's not correct for me to say that it ignores punctuation. More like it uses punctuation as tiebreakers. Not sure if that's a 100% correct statement either...